# ¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de almacenar en un solo campo de la base de datos la duración de un evento?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con PHP, mySQL y Symfony para gestionar reservas de eventos como cursos, conferencias , etc.

Además de almacenar un `datetime` para el inicio y el fin del evento quiero tener otro campo para la duración total. Ya que habrá veces que sabré cual va a ser la duración pero aún no habré determinado la fecha o la hora concreta.

Me gustaría utilizar el objeto `DateInterval` de PHP pero este parece admitir varios formatos, por ejemplo el formato de cadena: `'P1DT12H'` o el formato más parecido a una fecha: `0000-00-01 12:00:00`.

Podríais indicarme cuál es el más recomendado a la hora de hacer cálculos comprobaciones, etc. O si es difícil decidir ¿qué pros y contras habéis encontrado en el uso de cada uno?

Comment: Para una gestión completa de calendario (con sesiones en varios días, una duración diferente en cada sesión, o varias sesiones en un mismo día) no necesitarás un campo para ello, necesitarás relacionar en una tabla adicional los periodos y hacer un `SUM()` de los intervalos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta rápida es que no necesitas almacenar la duración de un evento en un campo, puedes calcularlo fácilmente en la propia consulta SQL y no necesitas ir recalculando la duración cada vez que cambies los horarios de las sesiones.

Si lo que necesitas es almacenar la duración "oficial" del curso para mostrarlo en un listado, entonces mejor que sea texto humano ya que no deberías usarlo para validar la duración real del evento si éste aún no tiene sesiones establecidas.

Como dije anteriormente, para una gestión completa de calendario (con sesiones en varios días, una duración diferente en cada sesión, o varias sesiones en un mismo día) no necesitarás un campo de duración real para ello porque podrás calcularlo fácilmente. Simplemente necesitarás relacionar en una tabla adicional los periodos y hacer un SUM() de los intervalos.

Imaginemos este esquema:

```
CREATE TABLE eventos (
  id INT,
  evento VARCHAR(250),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE sesiones (
  id_evento INT,
  descripcion VARCHAR(250),
  inicio DATETIME,
  final DATETIME,
  INDEX(id_evento),
  PRIMARY KEY(id_evento, inicio, final)
);
```

Creamos dos eventos así:

```
INSERT INTO eventos (id, evento) VALUES (
  1, 'Charla interesante'
), (
  2, 'Charla aburrida'
);
```

Y ahora agregamos las sesiones de los eventos:

```
INSERT INTO sesiones (
  id_evento, descripcion, inicio, final
) VALUES (
  1, 'Comienzo', '2018-07-04 10:00:00', '2018-07-04 11:00:00'
), (
  1, 'Teoría', '2018-07-04 12:00:00', '2018-07-04 14:00:00'
), (
  1, 'Práctica', '2018-07-04 17:00:00', '2018-07-04 20:00:00'
), (
  1, 'Examen', '2018-07-05 10:00:00', '2018-07-05 12:00:00'
), (
  2, 'Charla', '2018-07-06 08:00:00', '2018-07-06 23:00:00'
);
```

Con estos datos podemos comenzar a calcular la duración de cada sesión de cada evento:

```
SELECT
  e.*,
  s.*,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, inicio, final) duracion
FROM eventos e
INNER JOIN sesiones s
  ON e.id = s.id_evento
ORDER BY inicio ASC
```

Y si queremos calcular la duración total del evento podemos usar `GROUP BY`/`SUM` para ello:

```
SELECT
  e.*,
  SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, inicio, final)) duracion
FROM eventos e
INNER JOIN sesiones s
  ON e.id = s.id_evento
GROUP BY e.id
```

Para calcular la duración en minutos de cada sesión he usado la función [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) que nos permite calcular la diferencia en días, horas, meses, etc.

También podríamos haber convertido la fecha en marca de tiempo de UNIX para extraer fácilmente la diferencia en segundos. Existen multitud de maneras de calcular la diferencia entre dos fechas.

[Puedes ver en línea un ejemplo de cómo hacer el trabajo en este enlace.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cxLFNfZBUswi7oPU7DAtQq/0)

Answer (score 1):

en mi opinión dependerá del uso futuro que quieras darle. 
Por ejemplo, si en un futuro quieres agregar enlaces a archivos ics para que los usuarios agreguen automaticamente el evento a su calendario es mejor usar DateInterval pues es el mismo formato que usan los archivos ics aunque para hacer cálculos y comprovaciones te vendría mejor el formato de Time

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia @juananruiz
No importa que formato uses, lo importante es que lo estandarizares para todas las fechas.

Puedes hacer el datediff

```
$inicio = date_create(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),$variabledelaconsulta['date']);
$final = date_create(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$interval = date_diff($inicio, $final);
```

Ya después lo haces legible.

```
echo $interval->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:s");
```

P.D: Para estandarizar y no tener diferencias de horarios usa el.

```
date_default_timezone_set($zona);
```

[Listado de Zonas](http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.america.php),
[Date_diff](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-diff.php)